# How to stop windows service when trhow exception? NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an example for Windows service in .NET core 3.1.

I am generating an intentional error to see its behavior, my idea is that when the exception occurs I want to call the StopAsync method to stop the service, however once the StopAsync is executed the ExecuteAsync method is executed again and the service does not stop, entering like this in an infinite loop.

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        await Task.CompletedTask;

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                int num = 233;
                int result = num / 0;

                //todo
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                await StopAsync(stoppingToken); //this execute, but it keeps running this ExecuteAsync method
            }
        }
    }


    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("stop service");
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the ExecuteAsync method is executed again and the service does not stop, entering like this in an infinite loop.

Are you sure about that? [`StopAsync` will cancel the token provided to `ExecuteAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01b7e73cd378145264a7cb7a09365b41ed42b240/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L71), and it looks like your `ExecuteAsync` method will complete in that case.

The host application itself will continue running, though; perhaps that's what you're seeing. To shut down the host application when the background service exits, [you need to explicitly stop the application](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/backgroundservice-gotcha-application-lifetime.html):

```
private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;
public MyBackgroundService(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime) =>
    _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
    }
}
```